# Keras: training data format for seq2seq model

Tags: keras

I'm trying my hand at building an encoder-decoder architecture in Keras for training a (many-to-many) sequence model.

What I'm looking to make is a model that gets fed some text of variable length, say a news article, and outputs a summary of that text (also variable length).

My model looks like this:

```
# Encoder
model.add(Embedding(NUM_WORDS + 1, EMBEDDING_SIZE, input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, mask_zero=True))
model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE))
model.add(RepeatVector(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH))

# Decoder
for _ in range(NUM_LSTM_LAYERS):
  model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Which I think is about right. I'm preprocessing the input data as follows:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
  dataset = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
  texts = []
  X = []
  Y = []
  for row in dataset:
    texts.append(row['data'])
    texts.append(row['label'])
    X.append(row['data'])
    Y.append(row['label'])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=NUM_WORDS, lower=True, split=" ")

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
X_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
Y_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(Y)
X_train = pad_sequences(X_sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
Y_train = pad_sequences(Y_sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
```

In other words, a sequence like "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" gets converted into a sequence of numbers `[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,7,8]` and then padded: `[0,0,0,.....0,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,7,8]`. The target data (`Y_train`) gets converted similarly.

When I try to train the model, I get the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 200)`. I suspect this is because `TimeDistributed(Dense(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH))` produces a 3D output, but I'm not sure how I should format `Y_train` data to fix the problem?